# Lodash: tree shaking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tree-shaking

When I try to use lodash function as a specific import as shown below then it shows to be it loads only `14.7KB` in size.
[image]

But when I try to use the import as a destructured object then it shows `69.6KB` in size
[image]

Some articles say it works the same for both the above imports while some say it doesn't.
Just wanted to understand does it add the complete build or only a specific function in the final build, especially the 2nd syntax (destructuring)

Comment: use the `du` command line or the window explorer to compare the size of your build? Personally I would use `lodash/isEqual` in doubt

Comment: This isn't a question...

Answer (score 1):

```
$ npm i -D babel-plugin-lodash

.babelrc
{
  ...,
  "plugins": [..., "lodash"]
}
```

This will allow for any import style (e.g. `import _ from 'lodash'`, `import { isEqual } from 'lodash'` as the plugin will transform each usage of a lodash func to:
`import xyz from 'lodash/xyz';`

Comment: I still see the whole lib is getting bundled, even though I added this plugin to babel.config.js file as `const plugins = ['istanbul','lodash'];`